# OnClick Replace Image

Tags: javascript, html, image, button

I've tried to figure this out, but I don't know how to word it. This is the best way I can explain:

The HTML page loads with an image question.png

Then 3 simple HTML buttons appear, if button 1 is clicked, question.png is changed to image1.png, if 2, image2.png.

I can't make each button change question.png. Sorry for this stupid question.

Code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/83VSe.jpg